# Optimizing path conventions for urls.py

Tags: django, namespaces, django-urls

I am doing an online Django course and the instructor set two accounts in urls.py file as shown below:

```
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

Is there a reason to use this namespace convention? Is there a more optimal convention?

Answer (score 0):

From the Django docs:

"You can deliberately choose the same URL name as another application if you want to override a view. . . You may also use the same name for multiple URL patterns if they differ in their arguments."

Django assumes that your account view has a URL pattern with the name account. If you have a custom account view and give its URL the name account, Django can find your custom view with return() as long as it’s in urlpatterns after django.contrib.auth.urls is included.

You can read more here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example

To give you more information I would need to also see your imported views.